# Python VLC only works in python shell

Tags: python, mp3, vlc, python-vlc

I wanted to make a music player, and I'm playing the audio files via the vlc module.
I used this code to play the file:

```py
import vlc

p = vlc.MediaPlayer("music/song.mp3")
p.play()
```

in the python shell, it works fine and plays the file.
if I try to use a file and run it, it just exits without playing anything.

Comment: run `python script.py` in console/terminal to see if it displays error message.

Comment: maybe you have two Python installed and you use one Python to run `shell` and other Python to run script - and second Python may not have installed `vlc`

Comment: I ran it in the terminal, but it didn't display an error message.

Comment: It also works in a file if I put an empty input after the p.play() call, but I need it to work without it

Comment: now I see - `play()` starts playing music in separated thread so in main thread you can run other code. But if you don't run other code - like `input()` - then it ends script (and ends Python) and it stops thread with music. You have to run some code in main thread - to keep running Python and thread with music. It can be `while True: pass` instead of `input()`. Maybe module has function to check if music was finished - and then you could use it to exit `while True`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`play()` starts playing music in separated thread so in main thread you can run other code - ie. you can create GUI with buttons to control music, or display animation for this music. But if you don't run other code - like `input()` - then it ends script and it ends Python and it stops thread with music.

You have to run some code in main thread to keep running Python and then thread with play music.

It can be even `while True: pass` instead of `input()`.

In example I use `p.is_playing()` to run `while`-loop until it ends music.

```
import vlc
import time

p = vlc.MediaPlayer("music/song.mp3")
p.play()

print('is_playing:', p.is_playing())  # 0 = False

time.sleep(0.5)  # sleep because it needs time to start playing

print('is_playing:', p.is_playing())  # 1 = True

while p.is_playing():
    time.sleep(0.5)  # sleep to use less CPU
```

---

In `Python shell` you run `Python` all time so it can run thread with music all time.

---

**EDIT:**

Example which uses `tkinter` to display window with button `Exit`. Because windows is displayed all time so separated thread can play music all time.

```
import vlc
import tkinter as tk

p = vlc.MediaPlayer("music/song.mp3")
p.play()

def on_click():
    p.stop()   # stop music
    root.destroy()  # close tkinter window
        
root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command=on_click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Using `tkinter` you can build player.

---

`vlc` has few more complex examples how to use `vlc` with different GUIs

https://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=tree;f=examples;hb=HEAD

---

Function [is_playing()](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.MediaPlayer-class.html#is_playing) I found in documentation for [MediaPlayer](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.MediaPlayer-class.html)

Comment: I working on example with tkinter and button to stop music.

Comment: I added example with `tkinter`